# Which field is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a validation code as follows:

```
 if ((Info.LENDER_MAIL_STATE == "") || (Info.LENDER_MAIL_CITY == "") || (Info.LENDER_NAME == "") || (Info.LENDER_MAIL_ZIPCODE == 0) || (Info.LENDER_NAME_ID == 0) || (Info.LENDER_TYPE_CODE == "") || (Info.RECORD_ID_CODE == "") || (Info.RECORD_TYPE == "") || (Info.PORPERTY_FIPSCODE == 0) || (Info.RECORDING_PAGE_NUMBER == 0) || (Info.RECORD_ID_CODE == "") || (Info.RECORDING_BOOK_NUMBER == "") || (Info.CONCRNT_MTG_LOAN_TYPE == "") || (Info.DTBORROWER == null) || (Info.RECORDING_DATE == DateTime.MinValue) || (Info.PROPERTY_STATE == "") || (Info.PROPERTY_COUNTY == "") || (Info.PROPERTY_CITY == "") || (Info.PROPERTY_STREET_ADDRESS == "") || (Info.PROPERTY_ZIP == 0) || (Info.DOC_TYPECODE == ""))
            {
                return false;
            }
```

In this code any of the value is empty it will return false. I need to find out which value is null. Please help. We can achieve this by if else(individual check) that I know, but i need to know the value using this if itself

Comment: You need to check 3 if condition  with != ""

Comment: Check for IsNullOrEmpty

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the value of a particular variable, then you must use individual if else statement. There might be no way around that.

Although you can use the debugger and check it individually, but I guess for different inputs there might be different results

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange your code like:

```
if ((Info.LENDER_MAIL_STATE == "") ||
    (Info.LENDER_MAIL_CITY == "") ||
    (Info.LENDER_NAME == "") || 
    (Info.LENDER_MAIL_ZIPCODE == 0) ||
    (Info.LENDER_NAME_ID == 0) ||
    (Info.LENDER_TYPE_CODE == "") ||
    (Info.RECORD_ID_CODE == "") ||
    (Info.RECORD_TYPE == "") ||
    (Info.PORPERTY_FIPSCODE == 0)
   .....
{
      return false;
}
```

This will allow you to step in the debugger.

There is nothing wrong in using `else-if` construct. The performance will be the same plus this format is better for adding comments.

p.s. Our days the `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Info.LENDER_MAIL_STATE)` is the recommended function to check the string field.

Comment: so u are preferring individual check?

Comment: I would recommend to group 2-4 checks into one if statement. You will avoid too long lines. If you logically group them, the code will be easy to read.

Comment: if i group two more in one if,from that how can i check which one is null?

Comment: suppose if i check(first==""||second==""){}; if first is empty i need to show an alert(like first is empty),same for second.

Comment: If you want individual alert for each field, then you need separate if stmt for each field. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You are the best one to find which value is null by debugging the same, instead of `== ""`, check for `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Info.LENDER_MAIL_STATE)` and so on for each of them. Also check for `Info == null` is also needed

If you want to find which value is null by code you need to check each field individually `if statement` is what you can use for that.

Comment: would be better to use a string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() check.

Comment: @CodeUniquely, thanks for the comment if someone wonders which one and when to use have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976597/string-isnulloremptystring-vs-string-isnullorwhitespacestring

Comment: Yes indeed, I always us it in situations when the input comes from a third party (user, import or data source) as you never know what characters my be in the contents that IsNullOrEmpty misses.

Answer (score 0):

Ooooooops. There is no easy workarounds for what you are asking.

BTW have a look into a SO thread **[which-condition-is-true-in-an-if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102687/which-condition-is-true-in-an-if-statement)**.

Any ways my recommendation goes with a client side validation, probably jquery as you and your team are strong enough in the same.

Happy coding days. Cheers dude.